# How to create a blog plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actually not sure on the terminology of what I'm trying to do. I have a dynamic page (php) that I want people to be able to 'plugin' to their blogs. A couple lines of code that when inserted, insert the php page into their blog, like Google has a few lines of code to add Adsense into a page.

This is what I have which I think is right but how do I get the html, do I just use a post? There must be a simpler way?

```
<div id='fill'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
??? Code to get html ????
$("div#fill").html(html);
</script>
```

EDIT:Tried to reexplain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a simple html iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="50%" height="300"></iframe>
```

More on iframes:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: That should work, thx. Ill give you the check when the min time expires

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly now, you just want to load the contents from another site and embed them within your site.

PHP's [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will allow you to load whatever the other site's code is, and you could manipulate that with JavaScript/DOM, or use it in your `.html()` function (I won't go further now because I still don't know if that's what you really want).

Or you could just embed it within an `iframe`.